# Cassandra Secondary Index issue

Tags: cassandra

Is there any way to query a column family with secondary index, where column to  be filtered and column to be selected are of different data types. Any example code in hector is appreciated. I have tried it with indexed slice query, but different data type was an issue ..

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you using? In general you're better off not using secondary indexes and modelling (even if it means storing twice) so that you don't need them.

Comment: I am uing apache cassandra 2.1.2

Comment: I am using hector client to do that . not CQL (jdbc driver or datastax java driver).

Comment: I meant to put you should be using one of the modern drivers :)

Comment: . I have asked the same doubt as another elaborated  question , but nobody answered to that . The link is provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958275/hector-indexed-slice-query